# How to connect to public testnet without nodeeos?

Tags: testnet

We are building EOS dapp; we have build and tested in using local nodeeos, now we would like to deploy contract on public testnet but did not find any information about it. I can create account on jungle testnet (http://dev.cryptolions.io) but don't know how to deploy our contract on it using cleos.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks...

Raj

Answer (score 2):

If you've already made an account, ensure you have imported it's private key with

`cleos wallet import *private key*`

That way we can sign transactions as we need, now we need a node API endpoint that's connected to the JungleTestnet, I've found `13.211.220.84:8888`

Now we can simply deploy the contract with cleos like you do in the test net.

```
cleos -u 13.211.220.84:8888 set contract *Your jungle account name* /path/to/contract -p *Your jungle account name*
```

Comment: Is there a list?

Comment: On the http://dev.cryptolions.io if you click on organisation, under the ADDRESS & HTTP column are each node address and port.

Comment: use `cleos -u 13.211.220.84:8888 set contract *Your jungle account name* /path/to/contract -p *Your jungle account name*` . I got an error : ```Error 3090003: Provided keys, permissions, and delays do not satisfy declared authorizations Ensure that you have the related private keys inside your wallet and your wallet is unlocked. Error Details: transaction declares authority '{"actor":"tonytesttest","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it.```

Answer (score 0):

You can perform any actions including `set contract` by using Jungle testnet API's and no need to run nodeos in your system.

try `cleos -u <testnet api> get info`

- http://jungle2.cryptolions.io:80
- https://jungle2.cryptolions.io:443
- https://jungle.eosio.cr:443
- https://api.jungle.alohaeos.com:443

Try any one of these as `<testnet api>`

For complete list click [here](https://monitor.jungletestnet.io/#apiendpoints)

You can do the same for mainnet also

Try
 - https://public.eosinfra.io
for the mainnet